# Wordpress blog on Apache VPS

Tags: wordpress, apache

I have an existing site that is hosted on a LAMP VPS.  I also have a blog that is hosted on Wordpress.com/blahblahblah.  The goal is to have all of the traffic that goes to the blog at least go through the site to help with counting stats, SEO, and whatnot.  My complete lack of familiarity with Wordpress leads me to believe that the easiest way to accomplish this would be to create a Wordpress instance on the VPS and host the blog there.  I guess I'm asking two questions.  First, what are the pitfalls of hosting a WP blog on a LAMP VPS?  And second, is there an easier way to have that traffic pass through the existing site without pointless redirects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Wordpress will work fine on a LAMP VPS.
2. Traffic should not pass through another domain, because as you said that is a pointless redirect. I am not sure why you would not want to use one of the many analytics available such as Google analytics.

If you needed to you can setup the other domain and add an index.php file with a header('Location: wordpressite.com'); and whatever other code you want.

Another, cleaner, option is to edit the Wordpress site itself to send the information required to the other site by using a plugin or perhaps some javascript code.  This is typically what third party analytics plugins do.